# Change frame of label in table view cell

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

Yesterday I asked how to change the position of a label in a table view cell, but I still don't get it. Actually, I have a label in the right corner of the cell. When I change to landscape mode, it moves to the center, but I want it to be in the right corner. Please, someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx everyone it's done. I just set the frame for proper position and add to the contentView of tableviewcell.

```
lideCell1.sliderValueForSecond.frame=CGRectMake(25, 8, 400,23);
                slideCell1.tickLbl.frame=CGRectMake(430, -3, 27,40);
                slideCell1.tickLbl.text=@"+";
                slideCell1.tickLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:36.0];
                [slideCell1.contentView addSubview:slideCell1.sliderValueForSecond];
                [slideCell1.contentView addSubview:slideCell1.tickLbl];
```

Here slideCell1 is object of tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Article In witch I describe how to create custom `tableViewCell` may be it helps [Custom tableViewCell example with images and lables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273782/custom-tableviewcell-example-with-images-and-lables) Check it.

Comment: thanx but i'm in other tableview class and import tableviewcell of other class in that tableview class. there i want to change position of label during landscape. pls help me

Comment: hay everyone, last day I asked how to change position of label in cell but still i didn't get.
Actually I have a label at right corner of the cell when i make it landscape it comes at center but i want it should be at right corner. pls someone help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to customize you `UITableViewCell` instance, either by programmatically adding a `UILabel` object to it, or designing it through Interface Builder.

Once you have placed the label, to change its position you should consider editing its frame property.
E.g.:

```
UILabel *label = cell.label; // You should change this code to properly read the label
CGRect frame = label.frame;
frame.position.x = new_x_position;
frame.position.y = new_y_position;
label.frame = frame;
```

This way you can update the position of the label according to your needs.

If the problem you are facing is that of the correct positioning of the label while changing interface orientation, you should properly set the autoresizing mask for that component. To make it right aligned:

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

To make it left aligned:

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Also, you can choose to auto adapt the width of the label:

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Or, you can choose a combination of the previous ones:

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: CGRect tickFrame=CGRectMake(460, 110, 27,43);
[tickLbl setFrame:tickFrame]; I'm doing this one but not working.

Comment: How did you define the `tickLbl` variable? If you debug that line of code can you see if `tickLbl` is null or not?

Comment: hay everyone, last day I asked how to change position of label in cell but still i didn't get.
Actually I have a label at right corner of the cell when i make it landscape it comes at center but i want it should be at right corner. pls someone help me

Comment: I just updated the answer to face this problem. It is not a simple problem of position, but it's related to the autoresizing properties of UI components.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and override the `layoutSubviews` methods. It will be called when the size of the cell changes, for example when you change interface orientation.

In this method you call the super implementation first to properly update layout for content, accessory, backgrounds, etc. views. And then update your custom contents.

All your custom contents should be added subviews of the `contentView` subview of the table view cell, never as direct subviews to the table view cell. This is important, otherwise selection and highlight will screw up.

You could also make a subclass of `UIView` directly and use as a subview completely covering `contentView` and do the override of `layoutSubviews` there, without the need for calling the super implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If I want my `textLabel` indented by 16, then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I would type:

```
cell.indentationWidth = 8.0;
cell.indentationLevel = 1;
```

The cell property `indentationLevel` (a CGFloat) determines how many multiples of width `indentationWidth` (an NSInteger) to indent the `textLabel`.

The default value of `indentationWidth` is 10.0 and the default value of `indentationLevel` is 0.